# Adjust graph legend in R

Tags: r, plot

Could you help me adjust the graph legend. The graph is in the correct position, however I would like the legend to be outside the graph, that is, the image only needs to be lowered a little further.

```
A <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, 20, 2), y=rnorm(100, 20, 2))
B <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, 21, 1), y=rnorm(100, 21, 1))

par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 8.1), xpd=TRUE)

plot(y ~ x, A, ylim=range(c(A$y, B$y)), xlim=range(c(A$x, B$x)), pch=1,
     main="Scatter plot of two groups")
points(y ~ x, B, pch=3)

legend("bottomright",inset=c(-0,-0), legend= 3,title="The number is é:",title.col = "black", cex = 1.2)
```

[image]

**Example:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `legend(...)`, change value in `inset` will helps.

```
A <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, 20, 2), y=rnorm(100, 20, 2))
B <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, 21, 1), y=rnorm(100, 21, 1))

par(mar=c(8.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1), xpd=TRUE)

plot(y ~ x, A, ylim=range(c(A$y, B$y)), xlim=range(c(A$x, B$x)), pch=1,
     main="Scatter plot of two groups")
points(y ~ x, B, pch=3)

legend("bottomright",inset=c(0,-0.375), legend= 3,title="The number is é:",title.col = "black", cex = 1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Park! I inserted an image in the question as I would like

Comment: @CarlosJoseph I edit `margin` and `inset` of the code and plot. Please check it out.